# WooCommerce Custom Checkout Fields Based on Product and Quantity

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've put together a WooCommerce store that uses variable products to sell tickets to events based on location and date.

When a user adds a ticket to their basket and checks out I'm trying to get a series of custom fields to show based on the number of tickets they have purchased. So for example, the fields I need to capture are:

- Title
- Name
- Organisation
- Position
- Email
- Tel

These will be captured for each person attending the event (i.e. the number of tickets being sold). It also needs to be able to capture this information for each event that's being attended.

I stumbled upon a piece of code on GitHub - https://gist.github.com/joslex/43a5c90af83f9024fd80a71495eac4fc - which seems to hold the answer - the only problem is this part of the code seems to trip it up:

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

I've read that it has something to do with calling **cart->get_cart();** after **wp_loaded** but if I want these fields to appear before **woocommerce_before_order_notes** I'm not sure how to avoid calling **cart->get_cart();**

Here's the full code from GitHub:

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

$i = 1;

foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post;
    $quantity = $values['quantity'];
    $x = 1;

    while ($x <= $quantity) {

         echo '<div class="camper-group"><h3>' . $_product->post_title .  __(' - Camper ' . $x . ' Information') .'</h3>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'camper_name_' . $x, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('camper form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Camper ' . $x . ' Name'),
            'placeholder'   => __(''),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'camper_name_' . $x ));

        woocommerce_form_field( 'camper_grade_' . $x, array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('camper form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Camper ' . $x . ' Grade'),
            'placeholder'   => __(''),
            'options'       => array(
                'blank'     => __( 'Select a grade', 'wps' ),
                '1st'       => __( '1st', 'wps' ),
                '2nd'       => __( '2nd', 'wps' ),
                '3rd'       => __( '3rd', 'wps' ),
                '4th'       => __( '4th', 'wps' ),
                '5th'       => __( '5th', 'wps' ),
                '6th'       => __( '6th', 'wps' ),
                '7th'       => __( '7th', 'wps' ),
                '8th'       => __( '8th', 'wps' ),
                '9th'       => __( '9th', 'wps' ),
                '10th'      => __( '10th', 'wps' )

            )
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'camper_grade_' . $x ));

        woocommerce_form_field( 'camper_school_' .$x, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('camper form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Camper ' . $x . ' School Name'),
            'placeholder'   => __('The school your child will attend next fall'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'camper_school_' . $x ));

        echo '</div>';
        $x++;
    }

    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but this question is really not understandable… The code from GitHub is maid to generate custom checkout fields **for each cart item**… So please try to clarify **and to customize a bit the code with your needed fields**…

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is get the user to fill out details for each person attending the event. Basically if there have been 5 tickets purchased I need to collect the details of the 5 people attending the event. I'm really not sure of the best way to do this, but this code seemed like one solution.